# gethostbyname replacement for IPv6 addresses

Tags: c++, winapi, network-programming, ipv6

I have a program that uses gethostbyname (in Windows) in order to convert IP address to hostname.

But, it works only for IPv4...

What is the correct replacement for IPv6?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looking up [gethostbyname in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738524(VS.85).aspx) tells us that it's deprecated and we should look at [getaddrinfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738520(VS.85).aspx), which has all kinds of options for dealing with other addressing families.

Or if you're doing address to name translation, you'll end up at [getnameinfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738532(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: Developers are encouraged to use the `GetAddrInfoW` Unicode function (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738519(v=vs.85).aspx) rather than the `getaddrinfo` ANSI function.

Answer (score 7):

Use `getaddrinfo`, which deprecates the old `gethostbyname` function.

Comment: You **should** even use it for IPv4 addresses as well. You can produce protocol-independant code (same code that works for both IPv4 and IPv6) very easily.