# Can gethostbyname() return an IPv6 address?

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming, posix

I'm reading the **UNIX NETWORK PROGRAMMING**, and come up with a question about the exercise 11.4 to support the code with `gethostbyname` for **IPv6**. The answer in the book is as below:

```
#include    "unp.h"

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int                 sockfd, n;
    char                recvline[MAXLINE + 1];
    struct sockaddr_in  servaddr;
    struct sockaddr_in6 servaddr6;
    struct sockaddr     *sa;
    socklen_t           salen;
    struct in_addr      **pptr;
    struct hostent      *hp;
    struct servent      *sp;

    if (argc != 3)
        err_quit("usage: daytimetcpcli3 <hostname> <service>");

    if ( (hp = gethostbyname(argv[1])) == NULL)
        err_quit("hostname error for %s: %s", argv[1], hstrerror(h_errno));

    if ( (sp = getservbyname(argv[2], "tcp")) == NULL)
        err_quit("getservbyname error for %s", argv[2]);

    pptr = (struct in_addr **) hp->h_addr_list;
    for ( ; *pptr != NULL; pptr++) {
        sockfd = Socket(hp->h_addrtype, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

        if (hp->h_addrtype == AF_INET) {
            sa = (SA *) &servaddr;
            salen = sizeof(servaddr);
        } else if (hp->h_addrtype == AF_INET6) {
            sa = (SA *) &servaddr6;
            salen = sizeof(servaddr6);
        } else
            err_quit("unknown addrtype %d", hp->h_addrtype);

        bzero(sa, salen);
        sa->sa_family = hp->h_addrtype;
        sock_set_port(sa, salen, sp->s_port);
        sock_set_addr(sa, salen, *pptr);

        printf("trying %s\n", Sock_ntop(sa, salen));

        if (connect(sockfd, sa, salen) == 0)
            break;      /* success */
        err_ret("connect error");
        close(sockfd);
    }
    if (*pptr == NULL)
        err_quit("unable to connect");

    while ( (n = Read(sockfd, recvline, MAXLINE)) > 0) {
        recvline[n] = 0;    /* null terminate */
        Fputs(recvline, stdout);
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

With information on book and other resource, i found that the `gethostbyname` can't **return IPv6**. So my question is whether `gethostbyname` can return information about **IPV6**, or just the code is wrong?

I think this question is not about to replace the `gethostbyname`, i want to know the correctness of this code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gethostbyname replacement for IPv6 addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598965/gethostbyname-replacement-for-ipv6-addresses)

Comment: My question is also whether `gethostbyname` in **Linux** is different from the one in **Windows**, and may behave differently. And may be return the **IPv6**, according to the code above.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504810/how-do-i-find-the-current-machines-full-hostname-in-c-hostname-and-domain-info/505546#505546 and many others point to getaddrinfo. *shrug*

Comment: Use [`getaddrinfo`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getaddrinfo) instead. As mentioned by @alk and others, `gethostbyname` is deprecated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gethostbyname()` is not part of (the current) POSIX (IEEE Std 1003.1-2008, 2016 Edition) any more.

[It explicitly mentions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/netdb.h.html):

> The obsolescent *h_errno* external integer, and the obsolescent *gethostbyaddr()* and gethostbyname() functions are removed, along with the *HOST_NOT_FOUND*, *NO_DATA*, *NO_RECOVERY*, and *TRY_AGAIN* macros.

---

The last POSIX version supporting `gethostbyname()` was IEEE Std 1003.1, 2004 Edition, [which states](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/gethostbyaddr.html):

> ```
> struct hostent *gethostbyname(const char *name);
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> The *gethostbyname()* function shall return an entry containing addresses of address family *AF_INET* for the host with name *name*.

It does not mention `AF_INET6` at all.

---

So from the POSIX perspective your question about

> the correctness of this code.

can be answered as:

- Yes, it ***use to be*** correct, relying on an implementation defined/specific extension (namely support for `AF_INET6`).
- No, as of *now it is **not** correct* any more, as `gethostbyname()` had been removed from POSIX.

Answer (score 0):

You want the getaddrinfo function.

Comment: I think this answer could benefit from some additional elaboration.